# Use DataTypeAttribute with DataType.EmailAddress without validation

Tags: html, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

Look at almost any question about `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` and validation and you'll find someone stating that the attribute is not for validation but to allow rendering of the property as a mailto link with DisplayFor or as an HTML 5 "email" input type with EditorFor. The only problem is the attribute does cause validation. In my view model I have the property:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage="Invalid e-mail address")]
[Required]
[StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "The email address is too long")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

and displayed on a registration form as:

```
<div>
    *E-MAIL ADDRESS
    @Html.EditorFor(m => regVM.EmailAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => regVM.EmailAddress)
</div>
```

This renders an HTML 5 "email" type input, which is what I want and my reason for including the DataTypeAttribute. However, if I enter the value "asdf" into the email input, it displays the validation error message: `Please enter a valid email address.` Notice the attribute not only causes validation but also ignores the ErrorMessage I've provided (which, initially, I had not included under the belief this was not a validation attribute.) I am aware that you can use the EmailAddressAttribute to specify a custom validation message, but that's not my question.

I guess I'm looking to

1. Add to the web knowledge base that although the attribute may not
   be intended for validation, it sure includes it (if that is, indeed, the case)
2. Ask, "Is there is there a way to disable this validation?"
3. Get thoughts on why, if it's going to validate, which makes sense since DataTypeAttribute inherits from ValidationAttribute, does it ignore the ErrorMessage parameter? This seems like a bug. It basically says, "I'm a validation attribute...but only a little bit".

Notes: I had the unobtrusive, client-side validation enabled during my tests.

**Edit**
So I decided to do another test. I removed jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js from my page. Now I can submit an invalid e-mail address and ModelState.IsValid is true; it does not validate the e-mail address format. So maybe this is a bug with the client-side validation scripts.

Comment: Why not just set input type to "text", what other reason would you want to set it to e-mail, if you don't want it to validate the "@" and ".com"?

Comment: and for your 3rd question, it should not stop your error messages that are not caught by the "email" attribute. The "email" attribute is just looking for  "string"+@+"string"+.com or .net ect. but is not looking for input injections and such.

Comment: @Adam it's more about having control over my validation code, not having unwanted validation ocurring, and (see my edit) having client-side validation match server-side validation. Aside, you should be able to create a valid HTML 5 form regardless of your business/validation logic.

#3, Not sure what you mean by ""email" attribute". I'm talking about DataTypeAttribute not EmailAddressAttribute. But I wasn't saying it prevents other validation. It doesn't.

Comment: The email input type will do a basic browser dependent validation because that's what it's meant for. If you don't want that then use "text".

Comment: @Shoe ASP.NET MVC includes the novalidate attribute on the form. This is ASP.NET MVC validation, not browser validation

Comment: Circling back to @Adam's "what reason you would want to set it to e-mail": because it represents an e-mail address. Semantic fields are what HTML 5 is all about. Whether one chooses to validate the input, or at what point they choose to validate the input, should have nothing to do with the HTML. The field is still for an e-mail address regardless of its validation mechanism.

Comment: Yes, the `type="email"` semantically means "it's an email". However, there is a standard applied to the value that determines whether "it's an email" or not. If the value provided in the email input does not fit that standard then it isn't an email thus isn't valid input for `type="email"`

Comment: @Shoe The logic for determining whether the input fits that standard should not be defined by, or coupled with, the presentation layer, which is what the browser is in an MVC app and why browser validation and client-side script validation can both be turned off to allow the email input to accept _any_ text value (They can. Try it.) Aside from not being the way it really works, the point you're arguing is irrelevant to the question because the ASP.NET unobtrusive scripts are what are erroneously performing the validation. They are supposed to mirror the server-side validation, but they're not.

Comment: Remove the scripts and remove `novalidate`. If your browser supports HTML5 it will "validate". The semantics behind the value of `type=email` is that it's an email address. In order for it to be an email address it **must** fit a specific regex pattern. We can argue all day long about whether it should or should not be that way but the fact is that it's defined that way in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: @Shoe I defer to my previous comment. But ok. You've definitely established there is an alternative way of accomplishing the unwanted behavior.

Comment: The jquery validate script is probably automatically validating the email input via some JS. This probably is indirectly related to MVC because setting the datatype to email causes the input's type to be email.